# Ubuntu 14.04: Cant run sudo apt-get update or install anything

Tags: apt

Here is the error message I get when I run `sudo apt-get update`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Here is the output from /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Have yo utried another archive mirror, such as the US country mirrors?

Comment: Look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

Answer (score 1):

After wasting 6 hours on this, I used [RepoGen Ubuntu Sources List Generator](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) to generate a sources.list and used it. It works.